# Multiple consumer one queue

Tags: php, rabbitmq, amqp

Is it possible to make multiple consumers to share one single queue in RabbitMQ? I am currently using this [php library](http://code.google.com/p/php-rabbit/) to work with RabbitMQ, from what I observe, although I have 2 identical instances of a consumer script running, but only one would respond to the message passed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want both consumers to see all messages, give each consumer its own (probably private) queue and bind them both to the same exchange.